# How does exporting the express instance work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, express

I've came across code that goes like this

```
express = require('express');
app = express();
app.use(require('./lib/file.js'));
app.listen(80);
```

with file.js containing

```
express = require('express');
app = module.exports = express();
app.get('/blah', function(a,b){});
app.post('/blah', function(a,b){});
//And so on..
```

Can someone explain how does the `app = module.exports = express()` line works?

Comment: You'll see crap like this in a lot of Node.js modules. Not sure why people just don't put `module.exports = app;` at the end of their module code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app = module.exports = express()
```

could be also written as:

```
app = express()
app.get('/blah', function(a,b){});
app.post('/blah', function(a,b){});
module.exports = app
```

So it sets the module exports to an instance of express application (which, in turn, is a [connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) application).

The interesting part is the `app.use(require('./lib/file.js'));` which basically sets that exported application as a connect middleware. This is possible, because connect apps are in fact functions which can be used as middleware. You can see it clearly by looking at the code that creates them:

```
function createServer() {
    //the magic happens in the next line:
    function app(req, res, next){ app.handle(req, res, next); } 
    utils.merge(app, proto);
    utils.merge(app, EventEmitter.prototype);
    app.route = '/';
    app.stack = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
        app.use(arguments[i]);
    }
    return app;
};
```

Basically it's one of the ways to put routes in a separate file (in this case `file.js`).

Answer (score 3):

First, this sets the current module's exports to be identical to the express app instance.

```
module.exports = express();
```

This part of the line just creates a local alias to module.exports.

```
app = module.exports
```

The file you found could also have been written the following way, without the alias "app" for visual aesthetics.

```
express = require('express');
module.exports = express();
module.exports.get('/blah', function(a,b){});
module.exports.post('/blah', function(a,b){});
```

Also, note that having all that in two files is a bit redundant. The application is creating two instances of express app, and then having one of those instances listen to the other.

Comment: What do you recommend instead of having two express instances?

Comment: @mgoszcz2 you can have module exporting a function that takes the main app as parameter and 'enriches' is with routes, then call it in the main module. I wouldn't really worry about the extra instance that much.

Comment: I agree with @soulcheck, its not a problem. I just pointed it out because its not usual and I wanted to help illustrate how express works.

In our node applications, we tend to just pass around the app instance to route modules. So, we have a "routes" directory, and modules in there to organize different related routes. We simply require each route module and pass in the singleton express app instance to each module. Internally the modules just attach their routes.

Comment: @AnthonyHildoer sub-apps are pretty common way to structure your Express.js projects. I use both your way and sub-apps. The main down-side of sub-apps is that they don't share views with other apps. This is partly due to res.render and Jade being stuck in one directory. So if you have a part of your project that has it's own views or doesn't use views at all a sub-app is a really good abstraction.

Comment: @Pickels that is an interesting use. First thing I thought of was something similar to Apache's virtual hosts.